# How to download csv from uk government coronavirus api

Tags: java, httprequest, java-io

I've been trying to download the csv from the UK government coronavirus API. you can download the file manually by using the URL: https://api.coronavirus.data.gov.uk/v1/data?filters=areaType=overview&structure=%7B%22areaName%22:%22areaName%22,%22date%22:%22date%22,%22newCasesBySpecimenDate%22:%22newCasesBySpecimenDate%22,%22cumCasesBySpecimenDate%22:%22cumCasesBySpecimenDate%22%7D&format=csv

I've tried multiple methods of downloading files, such as JavaIO:

```
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = new URL("https://api.coronavirus.data.gov.uk/v1/data?filters=areaType=overview&structure=%7B%22areaName%22:%22areaName%22,%22date%22:%22date%22,%22newCasesBySpecimenDate%22:%22newCasesBySpecimenDate%22,%22cumCasesBySpecimenDate%22:%22cumCasesBySpecimenDate%22%7D&format=csv").openStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        Files.copy(in, Paths.get("test.csv"), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and Java NIO:

```
    ReadableByteChannel readableByteChannel = Channels.newChannel(url.openStream());
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
    try {
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("test.txt");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    FileChannel fileChannel = fileOutputStream.getChannel();

    try {
        fileOutputStream.getChannel()
                .transferFrom(readableByteChannel, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

however, it only shows this in the file:

```
    ‹ 0w®_ÿ}ZKŽX5Üs
àHm÷ÏÞ;$6ˆŒÈe‘€HâöTy²L=)Š”y»ÝŸru{^þ~}ùååãëxÿòåu|zý÷Ç—Ï¯Ÿøï×¿^ÿðñõÓOüñïÿ|üÆ¿ûíÓ‡/¯ï¿ÿùÃ§?Þÿùq,[önNü3,Ç\Çæ      ³1ÛN·wï£pvÆjÛ\Ï:Kâö˜§66_ez=ì¸}½Vœµ%®Æò•°rY•™Ä%p½`–õÔ¸ ®xŽ™§VKœ•8ÏÒ¶†Ï¨nZ˜ö<’1¦ÁË^ßÆÙ;®bÃ;V>•Ÿ³±V]\T[*ÜBÜÜž¶Âæ–¸M¿,œ×Ìjk\8ë8Ýˆ„!lE÷\'µuI¯¸³*¦KÜV+±¼²MÂ³Ýc#`Ka1¥¼ÆnØ6%l""|ì8=õˆô™c¯X-ã5óiïÑgŸl  CA2x4¼RGÂ÷èêÑyæ–Q˜HK„ °ˆ˜z5Dar¤WõÔG–ö‰X[ÃP[{ƒQE©i"Õ¦UXTF4†Êß£   ¬OJ‚H¬Y¾gËMÁbÈ7d²©tö’ÄÎ;!mûÊas u¤{Q°ìÁL°
Q@Éì‘YXTÂœ«9JP–Œ]†Ë¹qú¤ˆ‚WŸ‘`—1%{ùìBç·7µCRBÓ`Žo'‘æ@­šËÕ@I¼0À®-ˆ($Úe‘µED‰ªQ@ÊoJT¢à3Týt½* PZáHomjØòÑz°9¨æXÈò–(¤X¢¢EL¢9ÁµìÌ#½
"Š]ð½ùnix(Nùðõ…ÍÊ‰‚Òž¸®B;hYQ9 TZÊƒ»5ãáŒ÷" ª·½#îjÜß ÑÔgœØ•î
µ¢w4X³ö*èçÞÅ^å-íû ëk6Ûµî¶!­§|ŠèëZm=ÅËÖÓCç=M2çZöPC ‡†½3$
¾?Œ#Œ{@á
¦ös”H‰¼ßW2¥1L¸Í5
Ü4™Ñ¾MÈR HMk1LµÅmCÔ¦!*k¶DázÈ»£q…Û~
NJ…<ãß
‘ATÐzäÄ:ûa-§Vh—¹-€
 îÖÞ‚ç'³~ÕI½<ôÃÊNéÓIÏb
7¹õ»è7Ó;ÎÛÎ Ÿ¬“^ÊƒZ£¼Î-Õ=¡Ù–‘¦2šè Øýèýx%³Ê -VHÔ¢à!
ÂMzž²È!) <wëµèù¾Jê<+ñ:Ã•g!ý R‚Nˆá‘ 'Xÿ³]‡rè†™¬E5ÄëÓÑ›š6ýÔ$j£i’(g—7X×ƒñkP/¹UêHƒfò®TR¸4      b Å“M>:,U‹=K®Rrž—§Dmô(p¨!çS‚Ð1aðO!ñ    BIð6jG ‚\Üñi ¢HâJf­
‡F:‡7*Aë+Â@o7G#§»Ò-A66/}ôKžŽú(¸RÍ)#|å:á“¥ø¥ÉBÙ4µ§W*ÈÄ (R$ÔMÃ‘z»@…AsJ€ƒØn¯³TƒLÒ²x:t5ÚO‘ ùÃJ¤qqPŸ2vàŸžÜÎÜdf‚š34[Úþ)j†½¥0oòOS²eu‚~íÂÚ;K‚‚ú˜ ü@‚œ}@UKoÇV“Û•…t&NVµ(r$è·AEZ©É•Ð)­4>;Ð÷KrŠ¢7Ô­]·û‚@HŠªzk¾¾{A¬J{/úi–¢ßº¬ÒŒÒ†CßlºÀ¦’]uõ
ô'šc7éÌEãt½ãátðø†MJ%A`•ƒž}‘žävWÜ0.»GºœâÆ&MO‰âD’µÐhÍ¤«8ù1æ'aÚ®€¤æÑn˜ô:mÇå®Aœ/2_X1S¢&OˆµêÌÔ(
úƒŒ©=]ÚÎ‰4P…&U¢èù»V¶bŽ"½4çx¥jÙ$ôr)=ëª›É9dù,iª¶?«–…Œ!Õ“‰zJ£àù8Ø×Ìƒ·øhàì[Í½,oÃe›sOÔ~Iãs‡¨PLE…“œg¸˜b…ø w jÉv$oÃµ9G¸\¢PÅë-ô˜$oÃU´ýéƒõqÇg@åy°ÞyF¢"}K‚cÌÔ ü’(:´‘_`¤ÔÖßjåSÇví¯+œyË¡-i=1É]èòT{—•¶ó±Æ|VZFMšW,Ÿd%zócšôÇ&|Áü­íò·ñÍZ¦fýD-N°ÖìR•–w””X3Vh]ã&:  ‰â{ÿÞèé%jßVÿF‡&ãx§SÌBCO¥QèÞØÒO¨íX…¾¥6gó™Sæ=•óí èÒ_v9gé;´ïù‚†•Ñ2sŒÓâ‹B¼EN9'NÝWT×zs ¡@b½Ò[¢6wäs\ËÛ8È9A9‰Xºª¡ ç8ñ™]J9Ç;85
YAÎAïaœy…ºÑ‚œ“¸<AçðªF¡ç
ˆ—Hm}_œ8ÄvíUø~ƒ¿&@¨ârÎ¦]¨ðEßóê^ W¹#ÇÏ'ö½¤^=-Ä>hÛd'ß6’ívÅ”ùÎáÓ å‰ë8pßð¥Ð"ícÇ8ýú„dðå>’Æƒ„s‚óMFÚ8öO¹:µ@79‘Ñ]¥ã¶¹Ï¢=S»Óê><*Ó§#×@Ž õé-Ãª  Ü‡h¢æÑ§ƒÇûmŸÚO äzá/Ü4ßV‚HREï@¨!“Cmç—‹p    óbQÛù}žgÑ,ùJ[5^ü%ËÏID(a
9ßñËCF•n{éíòês’èÃvÍç{s½’ó*ä0¶R:“¿s€ìæ kIg¾Mš7
Aüj1÷õÙÛ)À)3ú!´uj²á$ŸsÞ®    apPz'4½ÕÒ‡“ï‘wâ(ÏÄ÷.ª„šÒdŠñ¥(ÐÉ5±o@5„/‚÷·…ô‰Ø‰€Aøm¶ç^òÈdÞ˜z‰ÅçPéöWdE½˜œ}¯<…­„. Žlx£Ë!“ð7jdºÞ‡«¡Ûº
^ŸùkQCåÖº³\¤üŽÃþò34Ô·ne5ú\·™ª?Y¬fzF~žüßú³áK¯¡xŸ¾îÇ¯ýøµ¿æã×xüê_×ãW:K¥¯dYŠ_¡¯†L?£¯dX=~Ej=|¥¯dbš?~]_§þ:ya?}Å7|ý:7é…)
```

I then moved on to trying to make an http request, which I used this code:

```
URL url = new URL("https://api.coronavirus.data.gov.uk/v1/data?filters=areaType=overview&structure=%7B%22areaName%22:%22areaName%22,%22date%22:%22date%22,%22newCasesBySpecimenDate%22:%22newCasesBySpecimenDate%22,%22cumCasesBySpecimenDate%22:%22cumCasesBySpecimenDate%22%7D&format=csv");

    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");

    int status = con.getResponseCode();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        content.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    con.disconnect();
```

which only returns

```
 0w�_�}ZK�X5�s�Hm���;$6��e��H��Ty�L=)��y�ݟru{^�~}�����x���u|z��Ǘϯ���׿^�����O����|�Ə���Ӈ/����ç?���q,[�nN�3,�\��       �1�N�w�pv�j�\�:K����66_ez=�}�V��%���rY���%p�`��Ը �x���VK���8����ϨnZ��<�1���^���;�b�;V>�����V]\T[*�B�܁���斸M�,���jk\�8�8��!lE��\'�uI����*�K�V+���M���c#`Ka1���n�6%l""|�8=����c�X-�5�i��g�l CA2x4�RG�����y�Q�HK�  ���z5Dar�W�����X[�P[{�Q�E�i"��UXTF�4��ߣ  �OJ�H�Y�g�M�b�7d��t����;!m��asu�{�Q���L�Q@��YXT���9JP��]����q����W��`�1%{��B�7�CRB�`�o'���@����@I�0��-��($ځe��ED��Q�@�oJT��3T�t�*�PZ�Homj���z�9��X��(�X��EL�9����#�"�]��nix(N������ʉ�Ґ���B;hY�Q9   TZ���5���" ���#�j�� ��g������w4X����*����^�-�� �k6۵�!��|���Zm=����C�=M2�Z�PC ���3$�?�#�{@���s�H���W2�1L��5�4�ѾM�R�HMk1L��mCԦ!*k�D�zȻ�q��~NJ�<��AT�z��:�a-�Vh��-����ނ�'�~�I�<���N��I�b7����7�;��� ���^ʃZ����-�=�ٖ��2�� ����x%�ʠ-VHԢ�!�Mz���!) <w����J�<+�:Õg!� R�N�ᑠ'X��]�r����E5���ћ�6���$j�i�(g�7X׃�kP/�U�H�f�TR�4       b�œM>:,U�=K��Rr����Dm�(p�!�S��1a�O!� BI�6jG �\��i �H�Jf��F:�7*A��@o7G#���-A66/}�K���(�R�)#|�:ᓥ���B�4��W*�� (R$�MÑz�@�AsJ���n��T�LҲx:t5�O���� ��J��qqP�2v������df��34[��)j���0o�OS�eu�~��ڍ;K���� �@��}@UKo�V�ە�t&NV�(r$�AEZ�ɕ�)�4>;��Kr��7ԭ]���@H��zk���{A�J{/�i��ߺ�Ҍ��҆C�l����]u��'�c7��E��t���t���MJ%A`���}���vW�0.�G����&M��D���hͤ�8�1�'aڮ����n��:m��A�/2_X1S�&O�����(����=]�Ή4P�&U����V�b�"�4�x�j�$�r)=몛�9d�,i��?����!Ս��zJ���8��̃��h��[ͽ,o�e�sO�~I�s��PLE���g��b���w j�v$oõ9G�\�P��-��$o�U����q�g@�y��yF�"}K�c�Ԡ��(:��_`����j�S�v�+�yˡ�-i=1�]��T{������|VZFM�W,�d%z�c����&|�������Z�f�D-N���R��w��X3Vh]�&:   ��{����%j�V�F�&�x�S�BCO�Q����O��X���6g�S�=���� ��_v9g�;�������2s���B�EN9'N�W�T�z�s �@b��[�6w�s\��8�9A9�X��� �8�]J9�;85YA�A�a�y��т���<A��F����Hm}_�8�v�U�~��&@���rΦ]��E���^�W�#��'����^=-�>h�d'�6��vŔ���� ��8p����"�c�8���d��>�ƃ�s���MF�8��:�@79��]����Ϣ=S���><�*ӧ#�@����-�� ܇h��ѧ���m��O �z�/�4�V�HRE�@�!�Cm痋p    �bQ��}�g�,�J[5^�%��ID(a9���CF�n{����s���v��{s���*�0�R:��s���kIg�M�7A�j1����)�)3�!�uj��$�s   a�pPz'4��҇��w�(���.����d��(��5�o@5�/�����؉�A�m��^��dޘz���P��WdE���}�<���. �lx��!��7jd�އ��ۺ^���kQC�ֺ�\�������34��ne5�\���?Y�fzF~������K��x���ǯ�������x��_��W:K��dY�_���L?��dX=~Ej=|��db�?~]�_��:ya?}�7|�:7��)
```

when outputting content.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It should be an `HttpsUrlConnection`, not an `HttpURLConnection`.

Comment: In violation of the HTTP protocol, the server returns the csv data with `Content-Encoding: gzip`, even if you explicitly send an `Accept-Encoding: identity` header. You will need to decompress the response body.

Comment: @Thomas how would I go about that? I'm not too familiar with decompression. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In violation of the HTTP protocol, the server returns the csv data with `Content-Encoding: gzip`, even if you explicitly send an `Accept-Encoding: identity` header. You will need to decompress the response body.

This constraint is actually [documented](https://coronavirus.data.gov.uk/details/developers-guide#request-headers) in the Developers guide for this API:

> All API responses are compressed using GZip. The request client must therefore accept GZip encoded content.

Something like this should work, and continue to work if the server starts sending uncompressed responses against our (now explicit) request:

```
    URLConnection connection;
    try {
        connection = new URL("...").openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
        connection.connect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
    String encoding = connection.getContentEncoding();
    if ("identity".equals(encoding)) {
        // Nothing to do.
    } else if ("gzip".equals(encoding)) {
        in = new GZIPInputStream(in);
    } else {
        throw IOException("Unsupported encoding " + encoding);
    }
    
    try {
        Files.copy(in, Paths.get("test.csv"), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Note that neither this code, nor your own, closes the connections and streams properly. I recommend to use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to close things gracefully even in case of an exception.

You could save yourself some headaches by using a third-party HTTP library, such as [`OkHttp`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/) or [Apache `HttpClient`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/quickstart.html).